# Why a shapefile of a geological data is not displaying the fault lines in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I am a new user of QGIS 2.4. and can not get a shapefile of geological data to display correctly. This shapefile contains polygons, fault lines, dips, volcanic structures, shoreline types, geological boundaries between other layers. Characters set: utf8. Reference systems: UTM WGS 84, Zone 17 North.

This layer was digitized from the geological map of Panama, 1:250,000.

When using ArcGIS the fault lines are displayed, but not when using QGIS. This shape contains the following extensions: .shp, .shx, .dbf, .prj, .qix., shp.xml.

What might be the issue?

Comment: I suspect this is an issue relating to projections.  Can you confirm that the digitized file was saved with correct CRS.  Also, when viewing the data in ArcGIS, do you have reprojection-on-the-fly enabled and/or the other data also in the same CRS?